# Misunderstanding a result with pandas using groupby and aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a dataframe which looks like that

| ID1 | ID2 | location1 | location2 | degree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S5 | S10 | Nice | Paris | 1 |
| S9 | S6 | Nice | Paris | 6 |
| S9 | S10 | Nice | Paris | 6 |
| S11 | S12 | Rome | Paris | 6 |
| S14 | S11 | Marseille | Rome | 6 |
| S15 | S11 | Les Brég | Rome | 6 |
| S11 | S16 | Rome | Paris | 6 |
| S13 | S11 | Paris | Rome | 6 |
| S7 | S8 | Batz | Nice | 1 |

I wanted to group by the columns degree,location1,location2 and then aggregated ID1 and ID2  as a list within the columns.

I did it with this line :

`df_merge = df_merge.groupby(['degree','location1','location2']).agg({'ID1': lambda x: x.tolist(),'ID2': lambda x: x.tolist()},axis=1)`

which gave me a correct output :

|  |  |  | ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| degree | location1 | location2 |  |  |
| 1 | Batz | Nice | S7 | S8 |
|  | Nice | Paris | S5 | S10 |
| 6 | Les Brég | Rome | S15 | S11 |
|  | Marseille | Rome | S14 | S11 |
|  | Nice | Paris | S9 | S10 |
|  | Paris | Nice | S6 | S9 |
|  |  | Rome | S13 | S11 |
|  | Rome | Paris | S11, S11 | S12, S16 |

However, there is two things that I don’t understand.
Firstly, if I swap the position of S6 and S9 from the first dataframe, I am getting this output.

|  |  |  | ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| degree | location1 | location2 |  |  |
| 1 | Batz | Nice | S7 | S8 |
|  | Nice | Paris | S5 | S10 |
| 6 | Les Brég | Rome | S15 | S11 |
|  | Marseille | Rome | S14 | S11 |
|  | Nice | Paris | S9, S9 | S6,S10 |
|  | Paris | Rome | S13 | S11 |
|  | Rome | Paris | S11, S11 | S12, S16 |

Indeed, it’s what I want, having only Nice and Paris as a location with all the samples in ID1 and ID2 and not having two rows Nice and Paris and then Paris and Nice as in the previous output. However, I don’t how to achive this.

Secondly, I don’t understand why columns ID1 and ID2 are not on the same row with degree, location1 and location2?

I converted my dataframe into a list, but I can’t figure out the organization of the list.

Many thanks in advance for some helps

Comment: I don't see how you can have `Paris/Nice` in the first output when you don't have this order in the input.

Comment: Using the original dataframe, and using the code provided - I get the second output

Comment: Sorry, I meant of you swap the position  of S9=ID2 and S6=ID1

Answer (score 1):

Using data provided in the first dataframe and your piece of code, I obtained the third dataframe in your question. I wasn't sure how you got the second dataframe, but it seems that you've switched ID S9 (id1) with S6 (id2) and also location Nice (location1) with Paris (location2). That's how you got the different results here

Sometimes using groupby creates multiIndex columns and you can use [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to get the columns on the same level after using groupby:

```py
df_merge = df_merge.groupby(['degree','location1','location2']).agg({'ID1': lambda x: x.tolist(),'ID2': lambda x: x.tolist()},axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: yes you are right, I got the second dataframe when I switched ID S9 and ID S6. The thing is, I have a lot of samples and sometimes I got the result as the second dataframe: two rows with Nice, Paris, S9 and S10 and Paris, Nice, S6,S9. But whatever the position of S9 and S6 (and others samples, here it's an example) I would like to always have the result as the third dataframe, a single row with Nice,Paris, [S9,S9], [S6,S10]. But I don't know what should I do to get the result always like the third dataframe.

Comment: in that case, you'd have to make sure that Nice is in location1 when Paris is in location2, regardless of switching ids in ID1 and ID2. it seems that when S9 and S6 are switched, so are the locations of Nice and Paris, so groupby groups them differently. there's a way in pandas to switch data in columns in case Nice and Paris are in the wrong position when degree is 6, I can write more about this if this is what you need but using different data samples will yield different results inevitably

Comment: yes It would be nice to get more information about that, please. I am a bit lost to achieve that. THanks

Answer (score 0):

So here I sorted each row to be sure to have every time the location1 and location2 sorted like:
Paris,Nice and
Paris,Nice
and so on for the other locations...

```
cols = ['location1','location2']
df_merge[cols] = df_merge[cols].astype(str)
df_merge[cols] = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df_merge[cols], axis=1))
```

and then I re-used the original line of code:

```
df_merge = df_merge.groupby(['degree','location1','location2']).agg({'ID1': lambda x: x.tolist(),'ID2': lambda x: x.tolist()},axis=1).reset_index()
```

Which now seems to give me the desired output. Any comments are more than welcome! Thanks for your advice.

Comment: However, in some circumstances, the np.sort(df_merge[cols]) put "nan" instead leaving the location. Any ideas of why?